# Парсинг JS с помощью PyQt5 + BS4 на Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

На англоязычной версии данного ресурса нашел код с использованием библиотеки PyQt5 который запускает JS html страницы. Успешно применил его. Но совершенно не понимаю логику его работы. А чтобы двигаться дальше, нужно разобраться.
Итак, сам фрагмент:

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


def main():
    page = Page('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
    js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
    print js_test.text

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Интересует логика работы именно PyQt5. Все что в главной функции мне понятно.
В дальнейшем хотелось бы видоизменить код, для того чтобы управлять веб приложением, а именно интересует нажатие кнопок и соответствующие переходы.

UPD 
Конкретный вопрос №1: какая логика работы этого класса?

Конкретный вопрос №2: при создании 2го объекта этого класса программа вылетает с ошибкой:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: Сформулируйте конкретный вопрос. _В дальнейшем хотелось бы видоизменить код_ - начинайте изменять под свои нужды, тогда появятся конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Конкретный вопрос №1: какая логика работы этого класса?

Comment: Конкретный вопрос №2: при создании 2го объекта этого класса программа вылетает с ошибкой Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: Сегментацию вы получаете потому, что `self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)` - объект приложения создается для каждого экземпляра класса, а он может быть только один.

Comment: Хм, как же тогда обойти создание второго? Но при этом загружать сколько угодно страниц для анализа?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос №2, решил таким способом

```
APP = QApplication(sys.argv)

class Client(QWebEnginePage):

  def __init__(self, url):
    print("Вызван метод __init__()")
    QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
    self.html = ''
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
    self.load(QUrl(url))
    APP.exec_()
  def _on_load_finished(self):
    self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
    print('Load finished')
  def Callable(self, html_str):
    self.html = html_str
    APP.quit()

 def main():

Client(url1)
Client(url2)
```

Comment: Сейчас возник новый вопрос, применив такое решени (вынос объекта QApplication вне класса), как создавать объект и вызывать методы, если этот класс у меня во внешней библиотеке находится (отдельный модуль).